# How can i get rid of "" in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am trying to represent JSON formated data Using React library Victory [here it is](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/).

example of component:

```
const data = [
  {quarter: 1, earnings: 13000},
  {quarter: 2, earnings: 16500},
  {quarter: 3, earnings: 14250},
  {quarter: 4, earnings: 19000}
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <VictoryBar
        data={data}
        // data accessor for x values
        x="quarter"
        // data accessor for y values
        y="earnings"
      />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, mountNode);
```

but I get my data from API in JSON format

notice format of data:

```
    const data = { "historical" : [
  {"quarter": 1, "earnings": 13000},
  {"quarter": 2, "earnings": 16500},
  {"quarter": 3, "earnings": 14250},
  {"quarter": 4, "earnings": 19000}
]};
```

What type of array is used in first fragment?

And how can I make it from the second?

Comment: this is a non-issue. JS doesn't require the quotation marks, but it's the same data. This should just work. If it doesn't, please let us know what the error or unexpected behavior is.

Comment: JS doesn't require the quotation marks but JSON does.  You just need to parse your JSON then pass in `data.historical`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data.historical` as the array in your component.